# Jquery class click 'this'

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am trying to make a dynamic iframe that changes its content page based on a picture that the user clicks on.

I have thus far, created the pictures and stored in the "title" attribute the element that is pertinent for the new screen. My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.item').click(function() {
      var title = $(this).title;
      var url = 'http://wiki.mainpart.com/' + encodeURIComponent(title)

      $('#innerdiv').attr('src', url);          

      console.log(url);
   });
});
```

However, this code does not work. The URL never has the title appended to it, the console log only shows the mainpart of the url. Could someone suggest a way I can get this to work?

Comment: What the other answers come down to is the fact that only a few, special attributes can be accessed directly as a property of an element. `title` seems not to be one of those. Thus you need `elem.attr('title')` when using jQuery, or using only JavaScript, `elem.getAttribute('title')`.

Comment: The real problem is that jQuery objects don't have the same properties as DOM Nodes. If title was a property that was available to the current element (which it is for images, in chrome atleast), you would access it directly on `this` with `this.title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     var title = $(this).attr('title');
```

Will get you the title attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
 $('.item').click(function() {
      var title = $(this).attr('title');   // <-- see change in this line
      var url = 'http://wiki.mainpart.com/' + encodeURIComponent(title)

      $('#innerdiv').attr('src', url);          

      console.log(url);
 });
```